# How to install ktechlab?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, compiling

How to install [ktechlab](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ktechlab/) in Ubuntu 11.10?
[image]

Comment: There used to be a package in Ubuntu repositories, but it's not available for Oneiric.  I wonder why was it removed.

Comment: It was removed because it relies on old KDE 3.x libraries. see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/727386 - according to that bug you can install the deb package from maverick.

Comment: How about some alternative to it?

Comment: I trid many alternatives , but Did'nt got a perfect replacement

Comment: See if [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_EDA_Software) or [this](http://alternativeto.net/software/ktechlab/) could help

Comment: @abcd did you try to install the deb from maverick as Alistair suggested?

Comment: @lumbric The expected behavior would be that it wouldn't install, because it depends on packages that cannot be installed (because they conflict with corresponding `qt4` packages). Still worth a try though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Compiling and Installing the latest *ktechlab* on Ubuntu 11.10+

This will get the latest, KDE4-port-in-progress *ktechlab* installed on Ubuntu 11.10 (and probably 12.04). Getting it to work may be a different story since I'm not familiar with the software. This assumes you are at the top-level of your home directory:

```
sudo apt-get install git kdelibs5-dev kdevplatform-dev qt4-dev-tools cmake libglib2.0-dev
mkdir git-ktechlab && cd git-ktechlab
git clone git://github.com/ktechlab/ktechlab.git
cd ktechlab
mkdir build && cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debugfull -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/
make
sudo make install
kbuildsycoca4 &> /dev/null
update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

And then run with `ktechlab`. Note that it segfaults for me when clicking "New" but appears to open existing projects successfully.

---

Alternately, short of setting up a virtual machine running Lucid, the other option may be to create a Lucid chroot, bind your home directory to it and set the X display appropriately so that ktechlab 0.3.x is running "natively" on your 11.10 display.

---

Somewhat off-topic: I've never used ktechlab, but have quite a bit of experience with embedded programming, in particular PICs; but most of it was using MPLAB (and a little gpsim) along with the ICD2 (in-circuit debugger) instead of a simulator. Perhaps an ICD might work for your purposes?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 64bits 12.04
With this script you can solved it:

http://elpuig.xeill.net/Members/rborrell/ktechlab-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Since the work of porting ktechlab has been, unfortunately, done in the spare time of the developers, it may be a very long time before we can use it in the latest versions of Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Xubuntu, etc).

However I came across this very interesting "how-to".

It made sense and I am in the process of following the instructions to install lucid 
in a chroot jail to run ktechlab.   It explains how you can configure it to set an icon on your desktop and a simple click from 12.04.

The site is in Portuguese, however if you use chromium-browser (and maybe others) you can translate it. Be careful with cut and pasting commands as the English translation of the commands added spaces. Just copy and paste in terminal the original text.
do each step in order.

Here is the site:
Click this link: [How-to install ktechlab using chroot for Ubuntu 12.04](http://sites.google.com/site/kitoeag/informatica/ktechlab-no-ubuntu-12-04-usando-chroot)

There is also a YouTube video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mXL3npIiT4).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

For those who like and need elaborations of electronic circuits with simulation of operation to facilitate the development we have again the ktechlab that was stopped for some time in its development, and only now it was released in .tar.xz which is the compressed source code which can be extracted for eventual compilation.

[image]

After a setback to put it to work, I ended up compiling, installing and creating a package in .deb format where in my tests it worked perfectly on the Ubuntu 17.04 base of KDu4 and the base Kubuntu 18.04 of KDu5 Alpha4. I believe it will work normally in other Debian-based distros.

- Ktechlab Application Reference: https://sourceforge.net/projects/ktechlab/?source=directory
- Download reference: https://sourceforge.net/projects/kduxp/files/Pacotes/Eletronica/KtechLab/KtechLab4.0/
- Ktechlab packaging 0.40: https://ufpr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/kduxp/Pacotes/Eletronica/KtechLab/KtechLab4.0/KtechLab0.40.1-build_20180303-1_amd64.deb To install, click and install or from the terminal: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install -f  && sudo apt install ./KtechLab0.40.1-build_20180303-1_amd64.deb` or `sudo dpkg -i KtechLab0.40.1-build_20180303-1_amd64.deb`
- Script for compilation of the source code (warning, from a workbook) Basic dependencies: git libqt4-dev kdelibs5-dev cmake https://ufpr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/kduxp/Pacotes/Eletronica/KtechLab/ KtechLab4.0 / Install-ktechLab-KDu4