# How to uninstall ktechlab?

Tags: uninstall

I recently installed ktechlab and it crashes a lot. So i want to remove it and reinstall it.

i used this link
 [How to install ktechlab?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116851/how-to-install-ktechlab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the exact same instruction from that question, when  you came to `sudo make install` use `sudo make uninstall` instead, if you were lucky it will be removed nice and easily otherwise you have to find and remove the files one by one manually.